# Ubuntu 20.04 refuses to boot in Dell G15 dualboot laptop - Platform does not support this image

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios

After an Ubuntu update my Dell G15 5520 laptop refused to boot to Ubuntu. (It's a dualboot configuration, Windows 11 worked flawlessly.)
The error message during the boot process:

```
Platform does not support this image
Failed to load header: unsupported
Failed to load image: unsupported
start_image() returned Unsupported
```

The first error message was something else (I didn't take a picture and can't recall it) but after some restart (and after put back Bios to default settings) I got these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the program called boot-repair can fix the machine.
I tried to boot from a bootable Ubuntu pendrive, but my Dell G15 laptop won't boot from the official Ubuntu image. (It can boot, but the live ubuntu will freeze after a short time.)

I used my already downloaded official Dell Ubuntu iso. (It is called dell-bto-focal-fossa-pybar-adl-X170-202111230-12.iso but I can't find a link to it. I guess I downloaded it from Dell support page.)
It doesn't really support live mode, I tricked it to run in live by starting a custom install (second option) and cancel it before it would do anything with my machine.

After I got the Gnome interface, could start terminal ([CTRL]+[ALT]+T), but I had no network. (I had only the lo device.) If you have network, you can just follow the instructions on the [official page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

I downloaded the boot-repair package and its dependencies to an other pendrive. (On an other computer.)
They can be found here: [boot-repair](https://launchpad.net/%7Eyannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair/+packages)
You will need to install them in the following order (by using the command **sudo dpkg -i** ):

```
1) glade2script-python3_3.2.4~ppa23_all.deb
2) glade2script_3.2.4~ppa23_all.deb 
3) boot-sav_4ppa203_all.deb 
4) boot-sav-extra_4ppa203_all.deb 
5) boot-info_4ppa203_all.deb (
6) boot-repair_4ppa203_all.deb
```

(I did this list from memory, please check the error messages. Also be sure that you use the right version for your ubuntu. For Ubuntu 20.04, you must use the **Focal** packages.)

After installing the deb packages, you can run the boot-repair command and that will fix your computer. (At least it fixed mine.)